# Set Datacontext of an ItemTemplate explicitly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have the following code below. The `WordList` is an `ObservableCollection` of `Word`'s.

The thing I am trying to accomplish is setting the `DataContext` of each item to a wrapper class `NewWordViewModel` instead of the `Word` objects which is  set by default. The `CorrespondingWord` is a dependency property of the `NewWordViewModel`.

The problem is xaml code creates a `NewWordViewModel` and sets it as `DataContext` but does not set the `CorrespondingWord` property to the actual `Word` object.

Is there a xaml way to set this property?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WordList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ui:NewWord>
                <ui:NewWord.DataContext>
                    <viewModels:NewWordViewModel CorrespondingWord="{Binding}"/>
                </ui:NewWord.DataContext>
            </ui:NewWord>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to move the `CorrespondingWord` property to the `NewWord` control and drop the `NewWordViewModel`?

Comment: OK, this works if I move all the contents of the `NewWordViewModel` to `NewWord` including the commands. However, how can I write tests for the commands now? The purpose of ViewModel was decoupling the classes and enabling unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a proxy to hold the implicit `DataContext` in each item and set the Binding to that normally, like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WordList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border>
         <Border.Resources>
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding}"/> 
         </Border.Resources>
         <ui:NewWord>
           <ui:NewWord.DataContext>
             <viewModels:NewWordViewModel 
                    CorrespondingWord="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
           </ui:NewWord.DataContext>
         </ui:NewWord>
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DiscreteObjectKeyFrame' target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')`. If I use BindingProxy class from [this](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) link, inheriting from `FrameworkElement` instead of Freezable, it does not output an error but all the fields on UI are empty. Is there a way I can debug which dependency properties are not set?

Comment: Actually the binding in `x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding}"` part does not work. If I write `Value="Some Text"` and create a TextBlock with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>` it does show `Some Text` on screen.

Comment: @qqww2 see my edit, in fact the proxy should be placed inside the root visual's `Resources`, not the `DataTemplate's Resources`.

Comment: When I override the `EndInit` method and look at `Tag` value, it is always `null`. I tried adding another dependency property to `NewWord` class and binding to it instead of `Tag`, it gives the same result. However, when I create an attached property it successfully binds to it. I don't actually understand this behavior. I expected the dependency properties would be bound before the `EndInit` method.

Comment: What the `Tag` are you talking about? The bound property here is `CorrespondingWord`. Looks like the editing value won't be available until it's committed by `EndEdit`. That's a normal behavior. I'm not sure why attached property works but do you mean it working here means the ***editing*** value is successfully bound to the attached property?

Comment: Am I seeing things? There was a Binding to `Tag` value an hour ago. Anyways, the property is not important. What I said was a bit misleading. Now that I looked at it again it just sets the attached property before the normal dependency property.

Comment: By the way this solution now throws an exception: `Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.`. The inner exception is `Cannot add content directly to this ResourceDictionary because its Source property has already been set.`

Comment: In fact I modified my code after some minutes. The exception means the `NewWord.Resources` was set somewhere else, such as in the XAML of the `NewWord`. Anyway you can wrap `NewWord` in such as a `Border` and place the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` in `Border.Resources` instead. The technique basically does not change.

Comment: Actually if the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` is defined in `NewWord` it triggers a chain. First it sets the `Value` to a `Word` object, then the new datacontext is created and the value is given to it. After the datacontext is changed the `Value` on `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` is updated to a `NewWordViewModel` and so on. Creating a border around `NewWord` and putting the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` to the border's resources fixes this.